# Use jquery to get closest previous div by id

Tags: jquery

Perhaps I'm just dense, but I can't work out how to get the div object with the id "getThisId" when "Option 2" is clicked in the btn-group div:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

  <!-- Here's the div element I want to get when "option 2" is clicked -->
  <div class="panel-body" id="getThisId">
    <div class="itemHeading">sub-heading...</div>   
    Text...
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button text... <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>

          <!-- Get the div with id "getThisId" when this is clicked -->
          <li><a href="#" class="confirm_test">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried various iteration of $(this).parent.prev and $(this).closest etc but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Just use the I'd as the selector, since id's must be unique

Comment: Out of interest, how would you do it by class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it is an id, just do a `$('#getThisId');` otherwise `$(this).closest('.panel-footer').prev().find('#getThisId');`

Comment: That `.find()` won't work. `find()` only searches in descendants, but `#getThisId` is the `.prev()` itself.